# Swift error with change from string to double (why String type number becomes nil?)

Tags: swift, string, null, double, option-type

I'm trying to make my own toy project to study Swift.
But I got a problem with converting string to double.

Please refer to the following codes first.

```swift
//MARK: - ExchangeManagerDelegate
extension ViewController: ExchangeManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateCurrency(price: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(price)  // [result] 1392.43
            let priceDouble = Double(price) ?? 0
            print(priceDouble)  // [result] 0.0
            let inputPrice = Double(self.currency1Price.text!)
            print(inputPrice!)  // [result] 10.0
            let result = Double(price)! * inputPrice!
            print(result)  // [result] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            self.currency2Price.text = String(format: "%.2f", result)
        }
    }
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

First of all, note that `price` is a string from JSON parsing and I checked that `price` prints out *1392.43* as I expected.

And when I tried to convert String(`price`) to Double(`priceDouble`), `priceDouble` seemed to be assigned as nil so it prints out *0* in the console.

So, I tried a different way with NSString, but it prints out *1.0*.

```swift
//MARK: - ExchangeManagerDelegate
extension ViewController: ExchangeManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateCurrency(price: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(price)  // [result] 1392.43
            let priceDouble: Double = (price as NSString).doubleValue
            print(priceDouble)  // [result] 1.0
            let inputPrice = Double(self.currency1Price.text!)
            print(inputPrice!)  // [result] 10.0
            let result = Double(price)! * inputPrice!
            print(result)  // [result] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            self.currency2Price.text = String(format: "%.2f", result)
        }
    }
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

Here, I want `priceDouble` to have *1392.43* and `result` finally have *13924.30*.
Please let me know why this problem occurred and how to change my code so that it works well.

Comment: Change `print(price)` to `print(Array(price.utf8))`. What is the result? For the string `1392.43` It should be: `[49, 51, 57, 50, 46, 52, 51]`. Most likely your result will be different if `Double(price)` is failing.

Comment: `NSString.doubleValue` is more permissif. You can compare values of `(priceStr as NSString).doubleValue` & `Double(priceStr)`, where `priceStr` is `" 1392.43"`, `" 1 392.43"`, `"1392.43"` etc. So as suggested before, do the print of each characters with `print(Array(price.utf8))`. You could also use a `NumberFormatter` to read the value.

Comment: Thank you very much, @HangarRash! I tried `print(Array(price.utf8))` as you suggested, and the result was _[49, 44, 51, 57, 50, 46, 52, 51]_. Here, I found that `price` actually includes comma and your comments played a decisive role in solving my problem! So, I finally solved my problem with `let priceWithoutComma = price.components(seperatedBy: [","]).joined()`.

Comment: Careful with commas. In some languages, it can be used to separate thousands, and other it can be used to separate decimals...

Answer (score 0):

`Double` can be initialised with any `String` (or technically any `StringProtocol`).  If that string is a valid representation of a number (in any base) it will return a Double of the respective value.  The string initialiser is failable and will return `nil` if it cannot convert the string to a Double.  (This is probably stating what you already know, but added just in case.)

On the surface it looks like you should be able to convert your string, but that the conversion is failing and the nil coalescing is providing a default value of `0.0`.  Removing the nil coalescing operator should provide a value of `nil` and would be a good check.

My guess is that the string coming from your json has non-visible characters or whitespace

Comment: I finally solved my problem. The reason is that `price` is assigned as _"1,392.43"_ (including comma), not _"1392.43"_. When I tried `print(price)`, only numbers without the comma are printed like _1392.43_ so that I could not recognize the comma in the variable. So, `let priceWithoutComma = price.components(seperatedBy: [","]).joined()` is my solution, and thank you for your fruitful comments.

Comment: Good that you solved it, but I hope you have control over the backend as in some locales a comma is used instead of a period to signify decimals.